# taxonomy term field in views

Tags: 7, views, ajax

I have created a autocomplete field with
 
function _autocomplete($string) 
 
but, I want this field result show in views.

do I use from `alter_query`?
 
I use from D7 and views 3.

thank you so much

Comment: You must give more clarification , and I will Help you ... what's the nature of this view , and also what's the replacement of $string parameter in the function ??

Comment: hello and thank you. I think it`s so explicit.I created an autocomplete field in a module and load it in my form(for example in node/add/news). when form is inserted,I insert my field result in a table in DB. now I create a views.I want show this results in my views.but this filed is not exist in views .because this field created in module and views cannot show fields and data from modules. I hope I can explain my Purpose